# Reading a csv file and writing rows to a second csv file in python that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, csv

The problem is how do you read text from one CSV file, identify a certain keyword in the file, read the rows with the keyword, and write those rows to another file. While this problem seems straightforward logically, syntactically it has proven challenging.

The code below is the code I have tried. Interestingly, the print(row) line is able to print exactly the information I am trying to write to the second CSV file. However, I have been unable to accomplish the same task with the CSV write module (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html).

```
import csv

csvfile = open('read_file.csv', 'r')
read = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in csvfile:
    if str('key_word') in row:
        #print(row)
        with open('write_file.csv', "w") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The code runs successfully. However, output appears random and disorganized. In essence, there appears to be problems iterating over the CSV file and writing the rows in an organized row-by-row manner.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Please add the csv sample and explain what is the condition that makes the row written to the output csv

Comment: if you open file with mode `w` in loop then you delete previous content. You have to open it only once at start, or you have to use mode `a` (append).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open both files in different vars before iterating. Don't open the target file every loop iteration. Also don't use `for row in csvfile`, use `for row in reader`

```
import csv

csvfile = open('read_file.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

with open('write_file.csv', "w+") as csv_file1: # different variable
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file1, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        if str('key_word') in row:
            # print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `csv` module at all

```
csvfile = open('read_file.csv', 'r')
with open('write_file.csv', 'w+') as csv_file2:
    for row in csvfile:
        if str('key_word') in row:
            csv_file2.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
with open('read_file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

#skip first line
#next(csv_reader)

with open ('write_file.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')

    for line in csv_reader:
        if str('keyword') in line:
        #print(line[2])
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```